# Checkout chosen files from master

Tags: git

I would like to download chosen files from remote GIT repository.
Is it possible, without local repository?

For example:

On remote GIT repository i got MASTER which contains files: FILE1.txt FILE2.txt FILE3.txt

I would like to download FILE2.txt. How to do that, with unix script?
I need to prepare a script which would download chosen file when run.

Comment: Are you using GitHub?

Comment: No. I'm using Bitbucket. BTW I need current version from MASTER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have http enable you can do, for example (on GitHub):

```
wget https://github.com/repository_name/blob/master/file_name
```

Or on BitBucket:

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/repository_name/raw/master/file_name
```

Just need to adjust the path to the file you want.

Comment: The repository is at BitBucket, not GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `git archive` command to create an archive containing the desired file(s) and immediately extract them.

E.g. (assuming *nix shell)

```
git archive --remote=<repo-url> master file2.txt | tar -x
```

Answer (score 1):

If your remote repository is accessible via http(s) or ssh, you can download selected files with any http-based tool/browser or sftp client.

Comment: Ok, sorry i forgot to write that I need to do that with unix(bash actually) script.

Comment: @MPAW just open this file in bitbucket web interface, click "raw" or something, and you will got direct link. You can use base url of this link for other files in this repository